# Find and store each max values from 100 different vectors and store them in a single vector at once

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a function that I use to do some calculations that returns a vector of numbers, and then I find the max of that vector. Right now I have to manually input the max value in a separate vector and combine it in the end. Is there an easier way to do it?

```
maxkl1 <- max(kldata_final1)
maxkl2 <- max(kldata_final2)
maxkl3 <- max(kldata_final3)
.
.
.
klall <- cbind(maxkl1,maxkl2,maxkl3,maxkl4,.....)
```

I have to do this 100 times, so I am thinking there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: sorry, I just tried to replicate an example, yes ```kldata_final``` are different objects.

Answer (score 1):

If the object names have all 'kldata_final' as common, use `mget` to return the objects in a `list` and then loop over the `list` with `sapply` and get the `max`

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^kldata_final\\d+$")), max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I will get a  new ```kldata_final``` each time I run the function that gives me ```kldata_final``` value, and I have to find the max of ```kldata_final``` for 100s of the vector.

Comment: So I guess I'm looking for an easier way to store 100 values at once without having to make 100 of ```maxkl1...``` vectors and combine them.

Comment: how are you getting kldata_final1, kldata_final2... etc ? by 100 repeated lines ? you should use iteration early and often.  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions

Comment: @NirGraham actually yes, I haven't figured out to iterate by saving the values I needed, so I had to do it manually.

Comment: definitely worth learning from the r4ds book, how to make those 100 more elegantly. but pkha above gave an elegant solution for gathering the different results and making a more succinct collection of just the max values, so you can press on with that I think.

Comment: @akrun sorry I'm a little bit confused, what would be the input in the lines above?

Comment: @akrun This is now working for me, however I have another question if you could help me out. The lines now will get the ```max``` value for all the vector with name ```kldata_final``` , is there a way to get not just the ```max``` value, but all of the values from the vector ```kldata_final```?

Comment: @pkha You can do `sapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^kldata_final\\d+$")), function(x) c(x, max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`